# A simple optimization problem

Tags: matrices, optimization

$$f = x^Tx$$
$$g = Ax-b $$

The constraint is $Ax-b = 0$

I calculated $J' = f'+\lambda g'$
which is $2x^T+\lambda A^T = 0 $ and $Ax-b=0$ .
I dont know what to do next please help me out .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much easier if you keep everything as a column vector.  Also, divide the objective function by two since a constant scaling of the objective function doesn't change the where the minimum occurs and makes the algebra easier since more things cancel.  Note,

$$
L(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}x^Tx + y^T(Ax-b) = \frac{1}{2}x^Tx + x^TA^Ty-b^Ty
$$

I flipped things around since I find the calculus easier.  Then,

$$
\nabla_x L(x,y) = x + A^T y
$$

The first order necessary conditions stipulate that

$$
x+A^T y = 0
$$

and

$$
Ax=b
$$

Putting this into one big matrix, we have

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
I & A^T\\A & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
b
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Through a long and arduous process, you can determine that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
I & A^T\\A & 0
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
=\begin{bmatrix}
I - A^T(AA^T)^{-1}A & A^T(AA^T)^{-1}\\
(AA^T)^{-1}A & -(AA^T)^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Basically, just multiply things together to check this formula.  Note, we've also assumed in this derivation that $A$ is full rank.  In any case, we have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
I & A^T\\A & 0
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
b
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
I - A^T(AA^T)^{-1}A & A^T(AA^T)^{-1}\\
(AA^T)^{-1}A & -(AA^T)^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
b
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 A^T(AA^T)^{-1}b\\
 -(AA^T)^{-1}b
\end{bmatrix}
$$
or that
$$
x=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}b.
$$
This turns out to be the minimum norm solution to an underdetermined system of equations.